# Cannot read keyboard shortcut text

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings

Some of the shortcut titles take up too much space and are truncated. System Preferences cannot be resized, so I cannot see the full name.

[image: System Preferences shortcut truncation]

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tooltips. Keep the mouse hovering over any of the abbreviated strings and a tooltip will show you the full text. This works in most of the OS.

[image]